# how would i put URL in xml data

Tags: xml

i have a big url which look like this

```
  https://r16---sn-o097znl7.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?sver=3&signature=780C4B1E55F0DF070DF4BBE3A7010E3DE761DADA.DA06E9F2D3A598FAC72C34D78708BB6181360CFB&key=yt5&mm=31&sparams=id%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Cmm%2Cms%2Cmv%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&id=o-AKY0A2_goQZdpF_RKZZzv_Qc1H07j-EjAkhu5K0BD-mr&mv=m&ipbits=0&initcwndbps=2840000&ms=au&source=youtube&ip=216.12.194.2&expire=1413538526&mt=1413516869&itag=17&requiressl=yes&fexp=908578%2C916941%2C927622%2C930666%2C930670%2C930672%2C931983%2C932404%2C934030%2C934601%2C940230%2C946023%2C947209%2C952302&upn=V5Ag-RQCarc&ratebypass=yes
```

i wanna put it in xml like

```
<xml>
<link> that big link </link>
</xml>
```

when i put it and open it it throws error how do i put it in xml could you guys help me out and thanks in advance

Comment: when i put that link in beween links and open it in browser it shows error at coloumn 1 and xml is not displaying

Comment: that really worked i wanna read this file and put value in array in java and its throwing error due to CDATA and bracelets do we have any other solution i can not replace those tags before reading though java and assign string to some variable i am using xml parser for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found after doing lots of headhache work finally found i jsut replaced & with &ampr of xml and it worked nothing changed and i used this small function to do it

$link = str_replace('&','&',$link);

Comment: Ironically this seem to be parsed wrongly by SO. What you mean is $link = str_replace('&','&amp;',$link);

Answer (score 4):

use CDATA and you are done

```
    <xml>
     <link><![CDATA[ your url goes here ]]></link>
    </xml>
```

Comment: that really worked i wanna read this file and put value in array in java and its throwing error due to CDATA and bracelets do we have any other solution i can not replace those tags before reading though java and assign string to some variable i am using xml parser for it

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options:

1. There are certain characters which are not valid in XML and you have to escape them:

   > < & ' "
2. Use CDATA

   < ![CDATA[ http://maps.google.com/FortWorth&Texas,more+url;data ]]>

Comment: that really worked i wanna read this file and put value in array in java and its throwing error due to CDATA and bracelets do we have any other solution i can not replace those tags before reading though java and assign string to some variable i am using xml parser for it